# Catching exception in Googletest Setup()

Tags: c++, exception, googletest

I have a test class which contains `SetUp()` and `TearDown()`, with certain inputs and is run with a variety of different inputs. When certain inputs are used, an exception will be thrown within `SetUp()` rather than in the body. This is expected and though it is not strictly part of the test, I would prefer not to have to move my `SetUp()` code into the body of the test just for this specific instance. However, I can't find a way of catching the exception here. My code is similar to the following:

```
struct MyInputs {
    int first_;
    const char* second_;
    const char* third_;
};
```

The test class is pretty standard gtest boilerplate:

```
class MyTestClass : public ::testing::TestWithParam<MyInputs> {
public:
    virtual void SetUp();
    virtual void TearDown() {};

    // etc...
}

void MyTestClass::SetUp() {
    // Do some stuff here using MyInputs.first_ which may throw
    // a "thrown from here" exception
}
```

I have a standard test closure though it's irrelevant to the problem here really - it doesn't get this far.

```
TEST_P(MyTestClass,aSpecificTest) {
    // ... some stuff ...
}
```

Then I create the loop with multiple inputs:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(MultipleTests,
                        MyTestClass,
                        ::testing::Values( MyInputs( 1234, "ABC", "XXX"),         // <-- No exception thrown
                                           MyInputs( 5678, "DEF", "ZZZ") ) );  // <-- Exception thrown
```

When I run the code, I get the error:

```
C++ exception with description "thrown from here" thrown in SetUp().
```

when it hits the 'bad' input. Is there a way I can catch this and either ignore or set an `EXPECT_` type clause? I realise that I can simply put a `try`/`catch` in the `SetUp()`, but  was rather hoping that I could use EXPECT_THROW somewhere to incorporate into the test.

Comment: You can use `ASSERT_/EXPECT_*` macros in the `SetUp()` function, but if you want the test to pass either the exception is thrown or not, I don't see another way that doesn't involve a `try {} catch {}`.